# Shiny App - Multiple Simultaneous User Access

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, shinydashboard

Im building a dashboard with R Shiny (shinydashboard package).

- After I deploy the application, i try to access it with two different systems using the remote machine's ip. I upload a file on one system, which runs perfectly. But as soon as i upload a different file on the other system, both the instances crash.

Is there anyway I can do an analysis of two different data sets simultaneously on different systems?

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example app? There shouldn't be any problem with multiple users on the same app.

Comment: Where is your app deployed?